# Single sign on using SimpleSamlPhp wrapper on Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5, simplesamlphp

Implementing single sign on in my laravel application. I have decided to use this plugin https://github.com/aacotroneo/laravel-saml2 which is basically a wrapper on famous SimpleSamlPhp.

I downloaded the code via composer and as per given information `Remember that you don't need to implement those routes, but you'll need to add them to your IDP configuration. For example, if you use simplesamlphp, add the following to /metadata/sp-remote.php`

```
$metadata['http://laravel_url/saml/metadata'] = array(
 'AssertionConsumerService' => 'http://laravel_url/saml/acs',
 'SingleLogoutService' => 'http://laravel_url/saml/sls',
 //the following two affect what the $Saml2user->getUserId() will return
 'NameIDFormat' => 'urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:persistent',
 'simplesaml.nameidattribute' => 'uid'  
);
```

I can't find `metadata/sp-remote.php`, any idea? and as far as `http://laravel_url/saml/acs` is concerned, do I need to deploy saml on the server? because at the moment the plugin code is in `vendors` in laravel core architecture code hierarchy.

Comment: Hi, so you have to install or config `SimpleSamlPHP` ? How is your SAML integration ? Can you give me some hints ?

Comment: @ihue i didn't get a chance to get back to that part, I might do that soon, not sure though.

Comment: I have the same question about installation. I am not sure if I need to pull it out of vendor and put it into the web root to make it work.

Comment: I didn't bring it in the root, i kept it in the vendor, added some code in the route as a call back. I will try to share the details and update the question. It worked finally. @dustbuster

Comment: Thank you my friend. I am fighting the same beast and it has been a few days. I am getting lost in my own head right now. If you're so inclined, I would very much appreciate it! I am having some luck with samllight. I got a response FINALLY!

Comment: @dustbuster added the answer

Comment: Hi. the package "[aacotroneo/laravel-saml2](https://github.com/aacotroneo/laravel-saml2/)" does not use [SimpleSAMLphp](https://simplesamlphp.org) but [onelogin/php-saml](https://github.com/onelogin/php-saml)

Comment: @Cyrille37aren't they all the wrappers over simplesaml?

Comment: @DanyalSandeelo No, there are 2 distinct implementations, like we can see in composer files, and source code ;-)

Comment: @Cyrille37 nice never looked into the details I implemented it in 2017

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this will help others. I added `saml2_settings.php` in the `config` folder.

Updated the routes:

```
'logoutRoute' => '/logout',
'loginRoute' => '/homepage',
'errorRoute' => '/error',
```

updated `x509cert` (publickey.cer) and `privateKey`

Updated `'entityId'`, added the url of metadata xml.
Updated `singleLogoutService` and rest of the required details in the `saml2_settings.php` file.

Added two listeners
1) for login event
2) for logout event

Updated the routes file like this:

```
\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Event::listen('Aacotroneo\Saml2\Events\Saml2LogoutEvent', function ($event) {
    \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth::logout();
    \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session::save();
    return redirect("login");
});

\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Event::listen('Aacotroneo\Saml2\Events\Saml2LoginEvent', function (\Aacotroneo\Saml2\Events\Saml2LoginEvent $event) {

    $user = $event->getSaml2User();
    $userData = [
        'id' => $user->getUserId(),
        'attributes' => $user->getAttributes(),
        'assertion' => $user->getRawSamlAssertion()
    ];


      // add the login for auto login based on your settings
    /// REDIRECT the user to homepage
    }
});
```

Comment: You are alright! Thank you! Anything that can get me a little closer to getting out of this hell i’m in right now I’ll gladly upvote the heck out of it! There is NOTHING on laravel and SSO!

Comment: but I still need to have that metadata inside the vendor/..etc.../simplesamlphp/simplesamlphp/metadata.php file, right?

Comment: are you using the same plugin that I have mentioned above? @dustbuster

Comment: I have EVERY plugin installed. This is a laravel 4 to 6 upgrade. Which basically is rewriting the whole thing. It was originally done with simpleSaml, but in my inability to get that working, I have tried saml light, and I tried aacotroneo/laravel-saml2: "^2.1" as well as trying to debug simple saml php I am just not having much luck. With aacotroneo/laravel-saml2 I don't get any errors, but nothing happens. It runs thru the logic, doesn't error, and I can't seem to find any logged response or otherwise. I did get Saml light to redirect me though. That was by far the most success I've had.

Comment: Also, I can't see to get a dd() to work in the Saml2Controller. I just want to dump out the login method, and it's just not running thru that code.

Comment: aacotroneo/laravel-saml2  for this , same thing happened to me. I eventually had to add event listeners in the routes file and it work. @dustbuster

Answer (score 12):

First some background:

There are two parts to any SAML interaction - the Identity Provider ("IDP") and the Service Provider ("SP"). The IDP is the master authenticator if you like, to which various applications (SPs) connect.

The idea is that the user visits your app, which in turn communicates as a Service Provider to the Identity Provider to get your credentials. And because multiple apps / SPs connect to the same IDP, you get the benefits of a single sign-on.

During the set-up phase, metadata configurations are swapped between the SPs and IDP to establish trust between them. This isn't user-level data -- it's application-level data that allows them to talk.

OK. So now on to your question:

The package you are using allows your Laravel app to talk to an IDP, but before it can do so you need to swap some metadata. The metadata for your app is the snippet above. This needs to go in the *IDP* configurations, which is where you will find this `metadata/sp-remote` (or more precisely `metadata/saml20-sp-remote`, which is where you paste this in.

If you haven't done so already, I'd recommend using [https://simplesamlphp.org/docs/stable/][1] as the IDP here as the Laravel package works with it pretty much out of the box.

One final tip: if you are using SAML2, then I found that you need to change the metadata key to refer to saml2 instead of saml above. ie `$metadata['http://laravel_url/saml2/metadata']` and not `$metadata['http://laravel_url/saml/metadata']`

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed description, appreciate it.

Comment: Amazing Answer, I wish I can give you 1000 upvotes. :D

Comment: Do we have to install SimpleSamlPHP to continue using this package = https://github.com/aacotroneo/laravel-saml2 ?

Comment: @ihue I have integrated as well, but when I get the valid response from SSO then I validate the laravel user so that it's auto logged it but seems like it can't do that.

Comment: @ihue here is the link to the question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44560598/authenticating-user-directly-in-laravel-using-a-test-route

Comment: I am about to jump down this rabbit hole. There's a whole lot out there for setting up an IDP but not a lot about SP. This explanation is very helpful!

Comment: @Fixspec i am trying first time this, I have my IDP metafile, and also have my SP platform in laravel , where should I add that IDP metafile in my application, I have send them my Metadata fle but I do not know where to add IDP metafile, can you please just help on this ? where to place the IPD metadata file.